# How to edit prettier config file to match JedBrain`s Rider inbuilt formatter configuration?

Tags: configuration, jetbrains-ide, prettier, rider, formatter

**Use Case**

In Our working environment there are developers who are using different IDEs to develop the codebase, some folks might use VSC some other use Rider, etc.

---

**The objective**

Each of these IDE has its own inbuilt formatter which are not the same. This naturally lead to unnecessary conflicts during rebase/merge. So, It was decided that we are going to use an extension, Prettier to have a common formatter. Prettier can be configured and thus everyone would have the same formatting no mater of what IDE they use.

---

**Solution (?)**

It was decided that most of the formatting needs to be similar to what Rider has to offer, therefore, one needs to create a new `.prettierrc` (*i.e. a prettier configuration file*) file which matches the format that Rider already offers.

And this leads us to the original question: `How to edit prettier config file to match JetBrains's Rider inbuilt formatter configuration?`

I wonder if anyone has done this already, perhaps share the config file.

Thanks for taking the time for reading this question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prettier is opinionated formatter with a very limited set of [configuration options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html), and its team is not going to accept any requests for adding new options, see https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html. So Prettier can hardly be configured to produce the same output as Rider formatter that has dozens of code style settings.

I'd suggest using Prettier as a formatter for your code in all IDEs, it can be set up as a [default formatter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prettier.html#ws_prettier_default_formatter) for JetBrains IDEs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after creating the question, additional research was done and we arrived at the same conclusion.